# Project Euler #1 python code not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

For Project Euler, [question #1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1):

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

I am trying to use Python, and I have the following code:

```
    def findNums():
        numsToAdd = []
        num = 1
        while num < 999:
            if 3 % num == 0 or 5 % num == 0:
                numsToAdd.extend([num])
            num +=1
            #print(num) optional
        for i in numsToAdd:
            lastNum = 0
            addition = numsToAdd[i] + lastNum
            lastNum = numsToAdd[i]
        print(lastNum)
    findNums()
```

But I get the following error when I try to run it:

addition = numsToAdd[i] + lastNum

IndexError: list index out of range

Could someone please tell me what this is and how to fix it?

Comment: Let's say `numsToAdd` is defined to be `[87, 134, 55]`: Do you then see how `for i in numsToAdd: x = numsToAdd[i]` can cause problems?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Project Euler specifically asks people not to post answer to their questions online. It would be poor form for StackOverflow to destroy their website by posting answers to all of their questions.

Comment: for starters, `5 % num == 0` - does this seem right ?

Comment: check the difference between `for i in numsToAdd` and `for i in range(numstToAdd)`. Understand how `for` loop works!

Comment: @theJollySin, That is not a valid reason to close this. It may be poor form, but this is a programming related question. SO is not here to enforce TOS or gentlemen agreements that other sites set up

Comment: @theJollySin If someone wants to find the solutions to project euler problems, I'm sure they will be able to regardless of SO.  The question itself has to do with programming, not solving the project euler problem.

Comment: `numsToAdd.extend([num])` is a slow version of `numsToAdd.append(num)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues:

```
if 3 % num == 0 or 5 % num == 0:
```

Your conditionals are backward. How you have it set up now, you are checking if 3 or 5 is evenly divisible by `num`, not if `num` is evenly divisible by 3 or 5.

```
for i in numsToAdd:
```

Assume that `numsToAdd` has the following values when you get to this point: `[100, 500]`.

When you get to `addition = numsToAdd[i] + lastNum` you are saying the following:

```
addition = numsToAdd[100] + lastNum
```

and

```
addition = numsToAdd[500] + lastNum
```

There isn't a 100th or 500th element. Instead, you can remove the indexing (to keep your existing format):

```
addition = i + lastNum
```

You could also do this to add up all the values in the list in one line:

```
sum(numsToAdd)
```

This can replace the entire `for` loop.

Finally, your first `while` is wrong:

> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

You are checking for everything less than 999. Change your `while` loop:

```
while num < 1000:
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your list `numsToAdd` has just 465 items in it.
Instead of this:

```
numsToAdd[0]
numsToAdd[1]
numsToAdd[2]
.
.
numsToAdd[462]
numsToAdd[463]
numsToAdd[464]
```

You are doing this:

```
numsToAdd[3]
numsToAdd[5]
numsToAdd[6]
.
.
numsToAdd[459]
numsToAdd[460]
numsToAdd[462]
```

The error occurs because your list index is out of range! There is no `numsToAdd[465]`!

Comment: Just use "i" instead of "numsToAdd[i]" !